# Strange Boost auto_cpu_timer undefined reference error

Tags: c++, boost

The code compiles and links just fine under Windows, however, on Ubuntu, when using the `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer(short, string);` constructor, the linking failed.

In addition, it is also strange that on Windows, I don't need to link to the boost chrono library, but on Ubuntu it is required.

main.cpp

```
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
int main()
{
// Link Failed!
//
// main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x96):
// undefined reference to
// `boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer::auto_cpu_timer(
//      short,
//      std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
// '
boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer(3, "Wall time: %w seconds\n");


// Link OK
boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer2;

return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(auto_cpu_timer_test)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Setup Boost
if (WIN32)
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR C:/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib)
    set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR C:/boost_1_59_0)
else ()
    set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /home/me/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib)
    set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/me/boost_1_59_0)
endif()

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS    ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED  ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
link_directories(${LINK_DIRECTORIES} ${BOOST_LIBRARYDIR})
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES} ${BOOST_INCLUDEDIR})

set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release" )

if(WIN32)
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd" )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT" )
else()
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11" )
endif()

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})

if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libboost_system-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib libboost_timer-vc140-mt-s-1_59.lib)
else()
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} libboost_system-mt-s.a libboost_timer-mt-s.a libboost_chrono-mt-s.a)
endif ()
```

Answer (score 2):

The most likely reason is that your Boost is not built in C++11 mode, but your application is built with explicit -std=c++11.

You can remove "bin.b2" and "stage" directories, and try again with:

```
b2 ... cxxflags=-std=c++11 linkflags=-std=c++11
```

The reason this is not an issue on Windows it that Visual Studio has C++11 on by default. The reason you don't need to link chrono on Windows is likely due to autolink - you add boost libraries to libraries search path, and you do no disable autolink, so all the necessary libraries are included automatically.